# Perform DB Update operation after Pear Download send

Tags: php, pear

I am trying to perform a db query after serving Download file.The script execution is stopped after the download headers are sent. Is there any way I could perform a script if headers were sent successfully ?

Here is my code so far ;

```
public function download(){

    require_once 'HTTP/Download.php';
    $this->load->helper('url_helper');

     $fname  = $this->input->post('filename');
     $path = 'public/Uploads/Films/files/'.$fname;
     $size = filesize($path);

     if(file_exists($path)){

      $dl = new HTTP_Download();
      $dl->setFile($path);
      $dl->setLastModified($unix_timestamp);
      $dl->setContentType('application/octet-stream');
      $dl->setContentDisposition(HTTP_DOWNLOAD_ATTACHMENT, $fname);
      $dl->send();
              // DB UPDATE BLOCK NEEDS TO BE UPDATED HERE

    }else{
        redirect('phome');
    }


}
```

Thanks, Any help much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to investigate more. Try to put this to your php file:

```
ini_set('error_log', "./php_log");
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Also put some debug info around `send()`:

```
$rv = $dl->send();
echo "send() returned: $rv";
```

Report back the result.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, and it does not log any errors. $dl->send() does return true or false based on the user action, However, the code after dl->send() does not execute. I want to check if the headers were sent successfully and do a db update. Thanks.

Comment: @Shane, thanks, strange. So you don't even see the echo after send? But then how do you now what `send()` returns, if you cannot execute any code after it?

Comment: Thankyou @tomas. the system does not echo what send()returns. I just told what its suppose to return. :)

Comment: @Shane what is "supposed" is irrelevant. It might return an error too. OK, this is really strange that the echo is not run. Is the script waiting then, or it finishes immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Pear::HTTP_Download->send() returns true or throws an error. Sinds you are not getting a value returned, there must have been an error thrown. Put a try..catch around the send method and see whats wrong.